# What text editor to use in conjunction with console commands that I am used to

Tags: linux, command-line, console, text-editor, cloud9

I'm very new to coding and have just completed an online course where the cloud-based system Cloud9 was used throughout. Now I'm starting my own project and I want to work offline. As such I've downloaded 'sublime text' which was recommended to me (I use a MacBook Pro) but I'm having a problem using the console. In Cloud9, I was used to using linux-style commands (cs, ls, mkdir) and it appears that to use Sublime I need to master Python. Whilst I want to do this at some point, right now I just want to get on with my project as my head is already filled with enough new stuff!! Can anyone recommend a text editor I could use with a console which does not require me to earn a new language?

Comment: I know that you seem to want something that doesn't have a steep learning curve... But I still will strongly recommend Vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Geany, it provides a built-in Terminal that will let you execute most unix commands.

https://www.geany.org/Download/Releases

---

From Geany's about page

Geany is a small and lightweight Integrated Development Environment. It was developed to provide a small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other packages. Another goal was to be as independent as possible from a special Desktop Environment like KDE or GNOME - Geany only requires the GTK2 runtime libraries.
Some basic features of Geany:
Syntax highlighting
Code folding
Symbol name auto-completion
Construct completion/snippets
Auto-closing of XML and HTML tags
Call tips
Many supported filetypes including C, Java, PHP, HTML, Python, Perl, Pascal (full list)
Symbol lists
Code navigation
Build system to compile and execute your code
Simple project management
Plugin interface (see Plugins)

Comment: Thanks guys. I've been playing around and actually I think just using the mac's terminal application will do me nicely! Cheers